# Binding onchange event using JS (Syntax error)

Tags: javascript, html

I've recently been spending some time playing with javascript event listeners in an attempt to learn a little more. However I've kinda hit a road block.

I appear to be getting a syntax error, `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'if'.`

> **The Question**
>
> If someone could elaborate and explain my mistake to me, I would be thankful. See the Js Fiddle for a more complete example of what I'm tryign to accomplish.

I've attempted to read up a bit more using **MDN** ([This Article Imparticular](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_token)) as highlighted by the console. However I'm failing to understand, my error and how it coinsides with this article.

```
function myFunction() {

  // Text field element.
  var a = document.getElementsByName('field-one')[0];

  // Checkbox element.
  var b = document.getElementById('box-2');

  // Select Element
  var c = document.getElementById('dept');

  // Bind onchange event.
  c.setAttribute('onchange', myFunction()),

  if (b.checked) {
    a.disabled = false;
    a.placeholder = 'Enter Your Full Name.';

  } else {
    a.disabled = true;
    a.placeholder = 'Not Applicable.';
  }

}

function myFunction()
```

> [**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/9fzqegso/9/)

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Regards,

-B.

---

**EDIT TUE 4 JULY**

I ended up completely reworking this to try and get things a little smoother. With some help from you all I was able to clarify I few things.

especially the key points highlighted by, @Kind User & @Shaminder S Aujla.

> - You have used comma instead of semicolon.
> - If you want to call the function, use just the name of the function.
> - Don't call the function while binding it.
> - Calling it like `myFunction();` will throw "Too much recursion error".

The resulting change is shown below and you can also see my finished fiddle [*here*](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/4kdo7em4/16/);

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Select Element
  var c = document.getElementById('dept');
  // Text field element.
  var a = document.getElementsByName('field-one')[0];

  // Bind onchange event.
  c.onchange = function() {

    if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 3) {
      a.disabled = false;
      a.placeholder = 'Enter Your Full Name.';
    } else {
      a.disabled = true;
      a.placeholder = 'Not Applicable.';
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks again all,
really appreciate it. :)

Regards,
- B.

Comment: Syntax error means that your js is not valid, like the sentence is not a correct part of the JavaScript language, meaning your code does not get executed at all.

Comment: @ Martin Meeser I'm aware of what a syntax error means, I was lack luster on why specifically it was throwing that particular error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have used comma instead of semicolon.
- If you want to call the function, use just the name of the function.
- Don't call the function while binding it.

  ```
  function myFunction() {

     var a = document.getElementsByName('field-one')[0];

     var b = document.getElementById('box-2');

     var c = document.getElementById('dept');

     c.setAttribute('onchange', myFunction);

     if (b.checked) {
       a.disabled = false;
       a.placeholder = 'Enter Your Full Name.';
     } else {
       a.disabled = true;
       a.placeholder = 'Not Applicable.';
   } 

  }

  myFunction();
  ```

```js
function myFunction() {

  // Text field element.
  var a = document.getElementsByName('field-one')[0];

  // Checkbox element.
  var b = document.getElementById('box-2');

  // Select Element
  var c = document.getElementById('dept');

  // Bind onchange event.
  c.setAttribute('onchange', myFunction); // semicolon + don't call it

  if (b.checked) {
    a.disabled = false;
    a.placeholder = 'Enter Your Full Name.';

  } else {
    a.disabled = true;
    a.placeholder = 'Not Applicable.';
  }
}

myFunction(); // call the func
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h3 {
  color: #fff !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

#txt-field {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

#col {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spacer {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.original {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 100%), url(http://imageshack.com/a/img661/3954/bwalqa.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.txt {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 200 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px !important;
  font-size: 26px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #272727;
  padding: .5em;
}

.stretch {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.shift {
  margin-top: 9%;
}

.boxes {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 100%);
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}


/*Checkboxes styles*/

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font: 14px/20px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #6cc0e5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .6;
  -webkit-transition: all .12s, border-color .08s;
  transition: all .12s, border-color .08s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  width: 10px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.selectpicker {
  margin: 3em 3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="txt-field" class="original box">

  <select title="Please Select" class="selectpicker" name="dept" id="dept" required="true">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Winter</option>
    <option value="2">Spring</option>
    <option value="3">Summer</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">Autumn</option>
  </select>

  <div id="col">

    <h3 class="txt spacer">Dynamic input, based on checkbox state...</h3>
    <input type="text" name="field-one" class="txt stretch" />

    <div class="boxes">
      <input type="checkbox" id="box-2" onChange="myFunction()" checked>
      <label for="box-2">Apply a name?</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: theres no need to call the function, its already called on onchange event.

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla So how can you actually **bind** that function with DOM element?

Comment: please check the provided fiddle, its called on onchange

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla Yeah, I can see it, but OP doesn't want to bind it strictly inside DOM, but inside the function.

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla But I don't say it's wrong, I would say that it's even better.

Comment: @Kind User I see, rookie mistakes but one has to make them to learn. :) Thanks for the assist on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in your code.
This:

```
 // Bind onchange event.
  c.setAttribute('onchange', myFunction()),
```

Please change to this:

```
// Bind onchange event.
  c.setAttribute('onchange', myFunction);
```

Also, when calling function, omit the keyword function:
So, call it like this:

```
myFunction();
```

Comment: I have tried this but it simply provides yet another syntax error, `SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script.`

Comment: calling it like myFunction(); will throw "Too much recursion error"

Comment: One should not call a function when binding it. Calling the function myFunction() vs binding it myFunction.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing semi-colon (;). Remove the comma and replace it with a semi-colon.
Look at this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fzqegso/10/).
 That Should be

```
// Bind onchange event.
  c.setAttribute('onchange', myFunction());
```

and remove the last line i.e

> function myFunction()

EDIT

Remove this line.

```
c.setAttribute('onchange', myFunction());
```

Call the funtion at the end like

```
myFunction();
```

Keep the inline binding i.e *`onchange="myFunction()"`*

Comment: yeah, thats y i removed the calling function in the last line, it will get called on the onchange of checkbox. Other wise it throws "too much recursion error"

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9fzqegso/26/

You have at least 2 issues

**1)** this must end with a semi colon:

Incorrect:

```
  c.setAttribute('onchange', myFunction()),
```

Corrected:

```
  c.setAttribute('onchange', myFunction());
```

**2)** Function must have a body:

Incorrect:

```
function myFunction()
```

Corrected:

```
function myFunction(){
//future codes here

}
```

I moved this codes into the function (myFunction) for it to work:

```
    // Text field element.
  var a = document.getElementsByName('field-one')[0];


  // Checkbox element.
  var b = document.getElementById('box-2');
    if (b.checked) {
    a.disabled = false;
    a.placeholder = 'Enter Your Full Name.';

  } else {
    a.disabled = true;
    a.placeholder = 'Not Applicable.';
  }
```

Comment: Seems that your jsFiddle has two same function declarations.

Comment: Thanks @VedranMaricevic I did forget to remove the first one. Fiddle updated